# User selects first word on line, but Safari selects something different (on website on iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xhtml

When the user wants to select the first word on the line, Safari selects something different:

[User tries to select "practical", but "very practi" is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avMVJ.png)

It doesn't make any sense. I have tried this so many times, it's not possible to be just "misclick". It happens in every first word each line.

I have special markup, when every word is one `<span>` element:

```css
.question {
  font-size: 2rem; 
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <span data-id="8897">The</span> 
  <span data-id="12072">coffee</span> 
  <span data-id="12072">table</span> 
  <span data-id="651">is</span> 
  <span data-id="5232">made</span> 
  <span data-id="5910">of</span> 
  <span class="test-fill">________</span>. 
  <span data-id="4357">I</span> 
  <span data-id="20645">do</span><span data-id="5744">n't</span> 
  <span data-id="8886">think</span> 
  <span data-id="4358">it</span><span data-id="651">'s</span> 
  <span data-id="9580">very</span>
  <span data-id="6273">practical</span>.

</div>
```

I tried other values of `user-select`, but it doesn't change anything.

Without `<span>`s it works just fine. But `<span>`s are important because `data-id` attribute...

Comment: This happens only on Safari?

Comment: @JayCodist it happends on Firefox and Chrome on iOS too. It do not happen on Android phones.

Comment: Really? Cos I can't reproduce this issue from your snippet

Comment: Yes. Can you try this https://codepen.io/petrhudik/pen/oNxwWvB ? This snippet doesn't work on my iPhone.

Comment: Nope. Still works OK